# Запретить Интернет

Tags: delphi

Нужно запретить интернет, когда нажимаешь на одну кнопку; а когда нажимаешь на другую, разрешить.

Comment: Вы бы еще спросили как отформотировать чужой винч ^^

Comment: это не вирус это для программы типа radmin

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял на Delphi?
Я знаю 2 способа:

1. С помощью функции WinAPI - **WinExec** открывать/закрывать (завершать процесс) программу сетевых подключений. Также можно использовать для этого **ShellExecute**. Подробнее об этих функциях найдёте в Сети
2. С помощью delphi-программы изменять содержание файла hosts на винде. Это может заблокировать нужный сайт или вообще почти весь Интернет.

Comment: А если отключать подключение к локальной сети?